# apache unable to serve django content - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

software versions - Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.4.3

clicking on this url [takingstock.in](http://takingstock.in) shows directory structure instead of serving views present in the document root. Have been going through a lot of articles on the web and queries on SO but all of them generally show that if the below steps were followed, apache should be able to serve the content. Please dont mind my rookie terminology , i have never configured apache before, let alone make django work with it. Kindly help ..

### Conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080> 
DocumentRoot /var/www/
     <Directory "/var/www/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/takingstock/website/wsgi.py
 WSGIDaemonProcess takingstock.in python-path=/home/ubuntu/takingstock:/home/ubuntu/takingstock/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
 WSGIProcessGroup takingstock.in
```

### /var/www - directory listing

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Apr 11 17:23 takingstock -> /home/ubuntu/takingstock/
```

### wsgi.py

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'takingstock.settings'
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/takingstock/')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

### error.log

repeatedly get only these lines (also a strange **"core:notice"**)

```
[Mon Apr 11 17:39:56.213262 2016] [:warn] [pid 6722:tid 140445589501824] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.4.0.
[Mon Apr 11 17:39:56.213327 2016] [:warn] [pid 6722:tid 140445589501824] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.4.3.
[Mon Apr 11 17:39:56.213910 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6722:tid 140445589501824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Apr 11 17:39:56.213925 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6722:tid 140445589501824] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

### access log

```
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - -     [11/Apr/2016:17:40:08 +0000] "GET /landpg HTTP/1.1" 404 496 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - - [11/Apr/2016:17:40:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 958 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - - [11/Apr/2016:17:40:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 962 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - - [11/Apr/2016:17:40:19 +0000] "GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 178 "http://takingstock.in/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - - [11/Apr/2016:17:40:19 +0000] "GET /icons/folder.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 179 "http://takingstock.in/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - - [11/Apr/2016:17:48:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 962 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - - [11/Apr/2016:17:48:07 +0000] "GET /icons/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 178 "http://takingstock.in/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
ip-172-31-17-34.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:80 122.181.181.230 - - [11/Apr/2016:17:48:07 +0000] "GET /icons/folder.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 179 "http://takingstock.in/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Where youve defined the <Directory> tag the path var/www should not be in quotes

Comment: Your DocumentRoot should be quoted: `DocumentRoot "/var/www/"` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot